# Topology surjective function question

Tags: general-topology

X, Y two sets, $f:X\to Y$ a surjective function, $\mathcal T$ a topology on X and $\mathcal T'=\{f(G) \mid G \in T\} $. Is, in general, $\mathcal T'$ a topology on Y? If not, find a counterexample.

I tried to take a y=f(G) and apply the topology axioms

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $Y=\{1,2,3\}$. Let $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=2$ and $f(4)=3$. Then, $\mathcal{T'}$ as per your definition is not a topology. Essentially, this stems from the fact that the inclusion $f(U_1 \cap U_2)\subseteq f(U_1)\cap f(U_2)$ may be strict for two subsets $U_1, U_2$ of $X$.

Comment: Ok, but in this case $f$ domain is $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and $G$ is from 
$\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,X,\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$, so what $f(\emptyset)$ will be equal to?

Comment: @mathlearner If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function and $U\subseteq X$, $f(U)=\{f(u)|u \in U\}$ by definition. Hence, in the above case, $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. Notice that any topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ is a subset of the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of $X$.

Comment: I still do not understand in which case there is a strict inclusion in the given example, why that makes $\mathcal T'$ not a topology. (T3) says The intersection of the elements of any finite sub-collection of $\mathcal T$ is in $\mathcal T$.

Comment: @mathlearner Say $U_1=\{1,2\}, U_2=\{3,4\}$. $f(U_1\cap U_2)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset \subsetneq \{2\}=\{1,2\}\cap\{2,3\}=f(U_1)\cap f(U_2)$. Here, we have strict inclusion. You can easily see that for NO element $U\in \mathcal{T}$, we have $f(U)=\{2\}$. So, in your notation, (T3) is not satisfied by the elements $f(U_1),f(U_2)$ of $\mathcal{T'}$